# D3js: finding path's bounding box (without getBBox() )?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, jsdom

The following code works on Chromium  :

```
var node = window.d3.selectAll('#L1 > *:nth-child(2)');
var bbox = node.node().getBBox();
console.log(bbox) // {height: 44, width: 44, y: -13, x: 144}
```

but not with nodejs + jsdom:

```
"TypeError: Object [ PATH ] has no method 'getBBox' "
```

M. Bostock pointed out that JSDOM [doesn't support](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/JyldAkWkTvI/n8thanJeGvAJ) `getBBox()`

**What D3js replacement to use to get the bounding box of `#L1 > *:nth-child(2)` ?**

Past efforts lead me there : `getBBox()` based [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/99dex43s/28/)

[image]

Comment: have you tried already with getBoundingClientRect? http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmcrrn.php

Comment: First try works on chromium [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99dex43s/29/) with some minor json key changes : `x` => `left`, but doesn't work on node `{ bottom: 0, height: 0, left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, width: 0 }`
 :(

Comment: I found out also offsetWidth, http://help.dottoro.com/ljfwvsrv.php but other than these three I can't really be of much more help. It's weird tho that even getclientrect doesn't work, it should as it works also with html and shouldn't be limited to svg only

Comment: It's weird getclientrect does works but send back null values... and as I'am printing out my svg, I can confirm the targets bbox are NOT null.

Comment: maybe something weird like strings getting returned instead of numbers? I'm a bit clueless honestly now

Comment: I get `0`, which is a number, and not `NaN`. Clueless too.

Comment: AFAIK, JSDOM doesn't support measurements such as getting the size or position of an element. That's because JSDOM doesn't actually lay out contents; it's strictly a DOM implementation. So you can call all the methods that a DOM has, like appending nodes and changing content, but never get any computed size or position info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Path's bounding box

Digging straight into the element's path data `d="..."` should work. An svg line is basically a set of `x,y` points. **Assuming absolute coordinates without translation nor big bezier curves**, which is the case of my D3js-generated svg lines, I'am finding in this data the min and max values for both `x` and `y`.

To do so, I get the `d="..."` svg line or multilines code. For simplicity sake, I rudely removes possible relative jumps such `h30` or `v20` since I never saw any in my D3js output, then clean out letters (aka `svg commands` : M,L,H,V,C,S,Q,T,A,Z), simplify the spaces and line jumps, then split by the remaining spaces. I get a clean arrays of coordinates.

Important to note, my selector directly target **a single non-translated path**.

```
var getBBox = function(selector){
    var xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax,p;
    // clean up path
    var t = d3.select(selector).attr("d");  // get svg line's code
    console.log(t)
   t = t.replace(/[a-z].*/g," ") // remove relative coords, could rather tag it for later processing to absolute!
        .replace(/[\sA-Z]+/gi," ").trim().split(" ");  // remove letters and simplify spaces.
    console.log(t)
    
    for(var i in t){    // set valid initial values
        if(t[i].length>1){ 
            p = t[i].split(","); 
            xmin = xmax = p[0]; ymin = ymax = p[1]; }
    }
    for(var i in t){ // update xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax
      p = t[i].split(",");
      if(!p[1]){ p[0]=xmin; p[1] = ymin;} // ignore relative jumps such h20 v-10
      xmin = Math.min(xmin, p[0]);
      xmax = Math.max(xmax, p[0]);
      ymin = Math.min(ymin, p[1]);
      ymax = Math.max(ymax, p[1]);
    } return [[xmin,ymax],[xmax,ymin]]; //  [[left, bottom], [right, top]] as for https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#bounds
}
var bb = getBBox("path");
```

[**JSfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwrmwxzt/11/)

#### Groups bounding boxes

For groups of multiple paths, you may want to traverse the svg DOM to loop upon each single path of the group in order to update xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax.

#### Translated elements

To handle translated elements, adapt further.

#### Alternatives

Other better approaches may exist. Remember to check if `getBBox()` and `getBoundingClientRect()` are available in your context, since they are native and very convenient.

Comment: getBBox returns a different value from getBoundingClientRect(). The latter returns a value relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `getBBox`/`getBoundingClientRect`/`getClientRect` does not work in NodeJS+JSDOM is that calculating these values of an SVG (or HTML) element involves massive amounts of computation.

First, all CSS code in `<style>` elements must be parsed (which is already not trivial). Then the CSS selectors, cascading and inheritance rules must be applied to know what size, position or line width an element has. And even after you know all style property values, you need to do some non-trivial maths to calculate the bounding boxes: definition of different SVG transform functions, compositions of these, bounding boxes of SVG primitives and Bezier curves. Browsers support all of these (they have to, in order to draw the element), but JSDOM is simply not meant for all of these.

But fortunately, **[canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg)** is a JavaScript implementation of most of SVG, which uses a `<canvas>` element to draw the image. It does support most of the above, and although it does not have an interface for giving you those data, fortunately it has very nice (and MIT licensed) code, so hopefully you can copy and reuse parts of it. As of now, the code is written in a single file, and it has [CSS parsing](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L2497), [applying cascading rules](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L861), [path data parsing](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L1316), [definitions of SVG transforms](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L581), [applying transformations](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L462), and [bezier curve bounding box calculation](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L529). That is, almost everything you need to calculate bounding boxes :) It does not, however, support CSS selectors, but it [can reuse another library](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/816e9d0d0dd8aa52ac89edca175d9ae360fcdeb6/canvg.js#L107). But unfortunately, as far as I can tell, canvg is **not** ready for running in NodeJS, you probably need some tweaks.

There is, however **[canvgc](https://github.com/nathan-muir/canvgc)**, an SVG to JS compiler, which contains [an older version of canvg](https://github.com/nathan-muir/canvgc/blob/master/src/canvg/canvg.js), and it **is** capable of running in NodeJS. So it is easier to start with that.